# When editing a question that isn't really good

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when I'm editing posts, I can see the question is not a strong fit for Stack Overflow, mostly because it is quite vague or open to debate.

So on those posts I just downvote, flag for a moderator, then skip it.

Is that the correct approach?

I tend to not try to refactor, because even afterwards I feel it would be a sinking ship still.

Some insight on how I can properly handle those would be very helpful so I can continue to contribute to Stack Overflow.

Comment: If the question cannot be salvaged, then just flag it. Throw in a downvote if you think it doesn't show effort or is low quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not possible for you to edit the question into something that would be appropriate on the site then you should vote to close for whatever reason is appropriate.  If you don't have enough reputation you can flag it indicating that it should be closed to bring it to the attention of people who do have the reputation to close it.

You can downvote such a question, but you're by no means *obligated* to.  Note that just because a question doesn't belong on SE sites doesn't mean it's a bad question.  Sometimes a person asks a very good question that just happens to be outside of SE's scope, in which case a downvote may not be warranted; but that's entirely up to you.

Comment: as always thank you for your awesome answer.  So I'm doing it correct.

Comment: `If it's not possible for you to edit the question into something that would be appropriate on the site` - you walk a fine line with this, yes, clean/fix a question if possible but **do not** *change* the intent of the question to "make it fit".

Comment: @Mike Discussing what types of edits are appropriate is really beyond the scope of this question.  You are correct, just because it's possible for you to edit the question into something that would be appropriate doesn't mean you should make that edit, but the point remains; if you can't edit it then you should vote to close.  Fortunately, the case of what to do when such an edit could be made, but would violate the rules for an edit, falls out of the scope of this question.  Since you brought it up though, such a question should also be closed.